# I upgraded Unity from 5.3 to 5.6 and now I get null reference exceptions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

Ok the problem is that whenever I want to use the UI text I need to convert my int values to string, so I made a method that simply took the Text variable and gave it the value of the Int variable I had so it could be used by the UI text object.

It looks like this:

```
void setText(Text textVar, int valueVar)
{

    textVar.text = valueVar.ToString();

}
```

pretty simple right? well.. im getting the error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson.FirstPersonController.setText (UnityEngine.UI.Text textVar, Int32 valueVar) (at Assets/Standard Assets/Characters/FirstPersonCharacter/Scripts/FirstPersonController.cs:1617)
UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson.FirstPersonController.generateRandomStat (Int32 stat) (at Assets/Standard Assets/Characters/FirstPersonCharacter/Scripts/FirstPersonController.cs:318)
UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson.FirstPersonController.charCram () (at Assets/Standard Assets/Characters/FirstPersonCharacter/Scripts/FirstPersonController.cs:221)
UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson.FirstPersonController.Start () (at Assets/Standard Assets/Characters/FirstPersonCharacter/Scripts/FirstPersonController.cs:1715)
```

So it seems the problem is generated in the method where I create random values, although like I said this used to work well before, here is the code snippet for the stat generator:

```
    //method to generate a random stat from 3 to 18
    public void generateRandomStat(int stat)
    {
        int rng = Random.Range(3, 18);
        switch (stat)
        {
            case 0:
                strength = rng;
                setText(strengthText, strength);
                print(strength);
                break;
            case 1:
                dexterity = rng;
                setText(dexterityText, dexterity);
                print(dexterity);
                break;
            case 2:
                intelligence = rng;
                setText(intelligenceText, intelligence);
                print(intelligence);
                break;
            case 3:
                wisdom = rng;
                setText(wisdomText, wisdom);
                print(wisdom);
                break;
            case 4:
                constitution = rng;
                setText(constitutionText, constitution);
                print(constitution);
                break;
            case 5:
                charisma = rng;
                setText(charismaText, charisma);
                print(charisma);
                break;
            case 6:
                luck = rng;
                setText(luckText, luck);
                print(luck);
                break;
            case 7:
                willpower = rng;
                setText(willpowerText, willpower);
                print(willpower);
                break;

        }
    }
```

The print() at the end of each case was used to first test in the console before using the UI elements, whenever I compile the game it doesnt even print the stats in the console.

Someone asked if I had assigned values to the Text variables, no I havent, all I did was initialize them as following:

```
public Text strengthText;
public Text dexterityText;
```

And so on, do I need to make them = to something to avoid errors?

Comment: Are you sure you're actually passing in an instance of the `Text` class, and not just null?

Comment: the `textVar` is being passed in null you need to follow the code backward and see where that value is comming from. That is where the problem is and that is the code you need to show us.

Comment: Yeah I checked the debug window further it seems the null value comes from where i generate the values ill edit the post!

Comment: Edited, now you can have a look to the method that generates the values, but it was working before! I dont know what happened after the update

Comment: Well, now point out which line is line 318 (from your error message `UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson.FirstPersonController.generateRandomStat (Int32 stat) (at Assets/Standard Assets/Characters/FirstPersonCharacter/Scripts/FirstPersonController.cs:318)`) and see which text is null, continue to follow it backwards till you see where that variable is assigned.

Comment: When I said "see which text is null" I meant which `Text` object that is being passed in as `textVar` is null, not the `valueVar`. A `int` can't be null. You sill have not shown us how you assign a value to `strengthText` and friends.

Comment: I havent assigned a value to strengthText and friends, they have just been initialized as: public Text strengthText; etc.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain finished editing the question.

Comment: Please start highlighting the text and pressing the `{ }` in the text box to format your code on the website if the preview looks incorrect. You did assign a value, you just did not assign it in code, you assigned it in the designer. You now need to check the script in your scene and check that the values are still assigned on the object the script is attached to in the scene (This is what the first half of Programmer's answer is explaining). This is basic debugging, when you have a error you need to keep following it backwards to the source, keep asking "Where did this bad value come from"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes when upgrading your project, you lose references in your scene. In this case, it looks like you lost the `Text` reference that is connected to `textVar` variable. Simply re-drag the Text component from the Editor the `textVar` slot.

I usually do that from script so that updating will not cause any of these problems:

```
textVar = GameObject.Find("YourTextObject").GetComponent<Text>();
```

**EDIT**:

With  your edited question, it's still the-same problem. Re-assign all your Text variables from the Editor such as `strengthText`, `dexterityText`, `intelligenceText`, `wisdomText`.... They lost their reference after updating. You can also do that in the Start function with the code above.

Comment: Thank you for the info I'll try it out to see if it fixes it!

Comment: THIS WAS THE FIX THANK YOU SO MUCH! Somehow like you say they lost their reference! now that I reassigned them in the editor they are working as intended, thanks a lot man you have no idea how I was smashing my head against the keyboard in anger and you are Godsent with an awesome answer, God bless you my friend.